# Sorting Dynamically With Links in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, sorting

I have a MySQL query I'm trying to sort dynamically when a link is clicked.

My link looks like this

```
                 <form action="topics.php" method="get" class="form">
                   <label class="label">Order Table By</label>
                    <li><a href="topics.php?sort=ID">ID</a></li>
                    <li><a href="topics.php?sort=Title">Title</a></li>
                    <li><a href="topics.php?sort=TAGS">Tags</a></li>
                    <li><a href="topics.php?sort=VIEWS">Views</a></li>
                 </form>
```

MySQL Query looks like this:

```
<?php

        $order = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']);          
$topics = mysql_query("SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title', 
                              topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_views AS 'VIEWS',
                       FROM forum_topics 
                       WHERE topic_id > 0 ORDER BY '$order' DESC") or die (mysql_error());
```

When I click any of the links above nothing happens. No error is shown, no sorting is done.
Where could the problem be ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $sortParams = ('ID','Title','Tags','Views');
  $order = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']);
  if(!in_arrray($order,$sortParams))
  {
    $order = 'ID';//Assuming by default you sorting by ID
  }  
  $topics = mysql_query("SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title', 
        topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_views AS 'VIEWS',
        FROM forum_topics 
        WHERE topic_id > 0 ORDER BY $order DESC") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting by `$_SESSION['order']` and not by `$order...` I would suggest replacing `$_SESSION['order']` with `$order` or do `$_SESSION['order'] = $order` before you create your MySQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have removed the $_SESSION['order'], but still not working

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Add that to your code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

If you have a closer look at your code, you can see that you are using `$_SESSION[order]` instead of `$_SESSION['order']` **notice the quotes**

**The true problem is:**

At line 1 you defined `$order`, and not `$_SESSION['order']`.

My tip is: get a proper IDE, a proper IDE like [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) will highlight a lot of mistakes you made like typos and unused variables. Can become handy when you have problems remembering your variables ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION[order]` is another variable other than `$order`. They are different, so that what you have done would not order anything unless you replace your `$_SESSION[order]` with the variable `$order` or they share the same value.

Comment: I removed $_SESSION['order'] and replaced with $order, but still not working.

Comment: @DotOyes, please add it as an **update** instead of an edit in the original post. For new visitors of this post, a lot of the answers look useless, but they DID help you. So please: ADD instead of EDIT to your original post ;)

Comment: Assuming that your query is: `$topics = mysql_query("SELECT topic_id AS 'ID', topic_head AS 'Title', 
                              topic_tags AS 'TAGS', topic_views AS 'VIEWS',
                       FROM forum_topics 
                       WHERE topic_id > 0 ORDER BY '".$order."' DESC") or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: If it still does not work, check your return value. For example, topic_id will return as Integer, and others will return as string values. Then using proper quotes at your `$order` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have quotes around `$order`, so it's sorting by a literal string, not a column. Change them to backquotes.

```
 WHERE topic_id > 0 ORDER BY `$order` DESC"
```